# Is Python available for Windows on ARM?

Tags: python, windows, arm

I know that Python is available for Mac and Linux on ARM because I have Python installed via Homebrew on Mac and it's ARM and I have Python installed via `apt` on Ubuntu and it's ARM. However, I can't find any download links for Python for Windows on ARM. The Windows download link on the Python website contain `amd64` so it is for x86, not ARM, and the [list of all links on the Releases page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/) only contains links for 32-bit and 64-bit x86.

Is there any way to get Python natively on ARM on Windows? Maybe there's a beta or experimental build, or an unofficial build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be supported starting with Python 3.11:

https://bugs.python.org/issue33125

> I'll probably make the ARM64 packages available through the Windows Store for 3.11's prereleases, and possibly as a side-loadable MSIX from python.org.

The same ticket also mentions an unofficial build for testing purposes:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/pythonarm64/

Comment: Thanks, I look forward to Python 3.11 then! In the meantime, I tried running the `Install-Package` command for installing the `pythonarm64` package as suggested in the link you sent, but it gave a message of `No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'pythonarm64'`

Comment: Sorry, I can't test this as I don't have an ARM Windows PC but maybe you should try downloading the package instead: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/pythonarm64/3.10.0

Comment: Unfortunately I can't figure out how to install NuGet natively on Windows for ARM, the website only has links for x86, and it's also included in Visual Studio which is x86 only. I also tried the .NET CLI option but it seems to only be applicable for installing into specific projects, not globally. I also tried `Install-Package python3` (just guessing the package name) which succeeded but it didn't add it to the PATH and I have no idea where it gets installed to.

Answer (score 3):

It is finally here: [Pyhton 3.11 beta 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110b3/)